# Why would Microsoft want NOT to fix the wrong implementations of Equals and GetHashCode with NaN?

Tags: c#, .net, hash, floating-point, nan

In the .NET Framework, the implementation (`override`) of `Equals(object)` and `GetHashCode()` for floating-point types (`System.Double` and `System.Single`) is **wrong**. To quote from the [MSDN `GetHashCode(object)` specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode):

> A hash function must have the following properties:
>
> • If two objects compare as equal, the GetHashCode method for each object must
>   return the same value. However, if two objects do not compare as equal, the
>   GetHashCode methods for the two object do not have to return different values.

If you take two `NaN` values with different binary representations, the two objects do compare equal under the `Equals` method, but the hash codes are (almost always) distinct.

Now, this error has [been reported](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/648567/) on Microsoft Connect. **But why will they not fix this?**

The fix is easy: Either let different `NaN` *not* compare as equal, or choose a fixed hash code to return for any `NaN`.

The fix won't break anything: The way things are today, nothing works when different `NaN` are used.

Can you think of *any* reason not to fix this?

Here's a simple example illustrating the current behavior:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

static class Program
{
  const int setSize = 1000000; // change to higher value if you want to waste even more memory
  const double oneNaNToRuleThemAll = double.NaN;
  static readonly Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();

  static void Main()
  {
    var set = new HashSet<double>();   // uses default EqualityComparer<double>

    while (set.Count < setSize)
      set.Add(GetSomeNaN());

    Console.WriteLine("We now have a set with {0:N0} members", set.Count);
    bool areAllEqualToTheSame = set.All(oneNaNToRuleThemAll.Equals);
    if (areAllEqualToTheSame)
      Console.WriteLine("By transitivity, all members of the set are (pairwise) equal.");
  }

  static double GetSomeNaN()  // can also give PositiveInfinity, NegativeInfinity (unlikely)
  {
    byte[] b = new byte[8];
    randomNumberGenerator.NextBytes(b);
    b[7] |= 0x7F;
    b[6] |= 0xF0;
    return BitConverter.ToDouble(b, 0);
  }
}
```

Result of running the code: One million duplicates in a `HashSet<>`.

PLEASE NOTE: This has **nothing** at all to do with the `==` and `!=` operators of C#. Please use `Equals` if you want to check this for yourself.

Comment: They said why in the article - they don't want to break existing code or backwards compatibility. Whether you agree with them or not, that's their reason and this question should be closed.

Comment: @SethCarnegie so... there's a question, and you have an answer. That's grounds for closing a question?

Comment: @Chris the question contains the answer.

Comment: -1: No research, the answer is in the linked Connect bug.

Comment: With the current implementation, existing code exhibits undefined behavior. Changing `GetHashCode` wouldn't break many existing programs, but it would fix some.

Comment: It is not as per [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). It solicits opinion.

Comment: Changing the semantics of `Equals` seems dangerous, but changing `GetHashCode` to make it consistent with `Equals` probably wouldn't break many programs. So IMO it should be fixed in the next major version of .net.

Comment: I'd suspect the real reason here is speed.  To handle NaNs properly in `hashCode`, you can't just scramble the bits and return the answer mod 2<sup>64</sup> or what-have-you; you need either a few clever bit-operations beforehand or a conditional and the cost associated with that.  (Of course, since this question is "not constructive", I can't post a more detailed answer.)

Comment: @tmyklebu I know what you mean. There's one "check beforehand" that they did remember and did get right. Positive and negative zero have different binary representations, but they they still `Equals`. Therefore both have to return identical hash codes, and this is implemented correctly.

Comment: Update: this bug is being fixed: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/13781 . It probably can be adopted in .NET Core 2.1.0

Comment: @JimMa Thank you for reporting the good news here.